# Notice: Undefined index: dlocation in C:\xampp\htdocs\ds\dsearch.php on line 48

Tags: php

I am getting following error when the html form is loaded for the very first time. Once I select the option from dropdown..all works perfectly fine.

Error I get is for th very first time:
**Notice: Undefined index: dlocation in C:\xampp\htdocs\ds\dsearch.php on line 48**

```
    <?php
        $queryfilter = "SELECT distinct dlocation FROM desmit";
        $resultfilter = mysql_query($queryfilter);
        $dlocationfilter=$_POST['dlocation'];
        echo $dlocationfilter;
    ?>

     <form name='frmSearch' action='' method='post'>
        <select name="dlocation">
        <option value="All">All </option>
        <?php
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($resultfilter, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $line['dlocation'];?>"> <?php echo $line['dlocation'];?> </option>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: Which is line 48? Try print_r() to check the variable. Also its a good idea to use `mysqli_*` or  PDO

Comment: It's not an error , It says some array index are empty

Answer (score 2):

I Don't know what you trying to do but use isset() function of php to take $_POST value

```
<?php
            $queryfilter = "SELECT distinct dlocation FROM desmit";
            $resultfilter = mysql_query($queryfilter);
            $dlocationfilter= isset($_POST['dlocation']) ? $_POST['dlocation'] : '';
            echo $dlocationfilter;
        ?>
```

Comment: Thank You So So very very much Amit. My problem is solved successfully .

Comment: Great pleasure here @vikramkapoor

Comment: Hi Amit... I am facing 1 more challenge if u can help me... When I scroll to next page.. my dropdown filter value gets reset to the first OPTION of select. how can i stop this from resetting , so that the drop down value remains same on every page instead of getting reset on each page.

Comment: You have to use session for that you store dropdown value to session variable and you can access this session in any page

Answer (score 0):

It say index of array not exists, so check index exists:

```
<?php
$queryfilter = "SELECT distinct dlocation FROM desmit";
$resultfilter = mysql_query($queryfilter);
$dlocationfilter=f(isset($_POST['dlocation']) && $_POST['dlocation']) ? $_POST['dlocation'] : null;
echo $dlocationfilter;
?>

<form name='frmSearch' action='' method='post'>
    <select name="dlocation">
        <option value="All">All </option>
        <?php
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($resultfilter, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            if(isset($line['dlocation']) && $line['dlocation']) {
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $line['dlocation'];?>"> <?php echo $line['dlocation'];?> </option>
            <?php
            }

        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

add this line to your `.htaccess` to hide notice:

```
php_flag display_errors off
```